# Prove $f(x)=x$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

Prove that $f(x)=x$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1]$.

My definition of integrable comes from Royden's Real Analysis (4th ed). So $f$ is integrable if the lower integral is equal to the upper integral and finite.

Lower integral: $$\inf \left\{ \int_a^b \phi(x) dx: \phi \text{ is simple and for all }x \in [0,1], \phi(x) \leq f(x) \right\}$$

Upper integral is similarly defined with $\sup$ (instead of $\inf$) and $\phi(x) \geq f(x)$.

For simple function $\phi(x)= \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i 1_{A_i} $, the integral is defined to be: $$\int_a^b \phi(x)dx = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i m(A_i).$$

I can prove this using theorems but I want to do it directly from the definition.

We have proven that we can approximate any function (within $\varepsilon$) using simple functions. I am not sure if this is helpful.

The first thing I pictured was "staircase" functions but I wasn't sure if I could pick my own sequence of simple functions. Don't  I need to consider ALL of the simple functions less than or equal to $f$?

Comment: since ->you<- want to do it by definition maybe you should show some of your work :)

Comment: Hint: consider simple functions that look like staircases.

Comment: I think I've seen definitions involving upper and lower integrals applied to Riemann integrals and Riemann--Stieltjes integrals but not to Lebesgue integrals.  The definition I've seen for the Lebesgue integral of a non-negative measurable function is the supremum of non-negative measurable simple functions that are less than or equal to the function whose integral one seeks.  For negative-valued functions one does the  obvious thing with minus signs, and for real-valued functions one looks at the negative and non-negative parts separately.  And Lebesgue integrable means$\ldots$

Comment: $\ldots$that the integral of the absolute value of the function is finite.

Comment: If a function $f$ is non-negative and measurable and dominated by a simple function whose integral is finite, then $\int|f|<\infty$, so it's Lebesuge-integrable. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: So, I guess you haven't read Royden :-)  I suppose his definition has the advantage of not requiring you to first define "Lebesgue measurable function".

Comment: I've read only a few parts of Royden.  I think of the definition of Lebesgue integral of a non-negative function as simply the smallest number that's not too small (and $+\infty$ if all numbers are too small).  And "too small" is defined using simple functions.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for the hint! It worked out perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

Partition $[0,1]$ into $1/n$ long intervals and take the following simple functions:

$g(x) = \frac{i-1}{n}, \ $ if $ \frac{i-1}{n} \leq x < \frac{i}{n}$ where $i=1,2,\cdots,n$.

$h(x) = \frac{i}{n}, \quad $ if $ \frac{i-1}{n} \leq x < \frac{i}{n}$ where $i=1,2,\cdots,n$.

Obviously,
$$
g \leq f \leq h \,
$$
And
$$
\int g \leq \int_* f \leq \int^*f \leq \int h \ .
$$
But also,
$$
0 \leq \int^* f -\int_ *f \leq \int h - \int g \leq \frac{1}{n} \ .
$$
Since $n$ was arbitrary, this forces
$$
\int^* f -\int_ *f = 0 \ .
$$

Comment: What is the best book for study measure theory for students with a basic background in calculus ? there are tons of them out there but it seems that those authors just want to write it to themselves and students got confused when they read them.

Comment: That is a very difficult question to answer. It depends on whether you need measure theory for geometry, for functional analysis, for abstract measure theory, etc. Every author has their own taste and you must find one that matches your best. Maybe check contents pages of the famous ones and if possible see sample theorems and proofs to see how abstract they are and whether you like the style. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Royden book is suck. I read it and I had to decompress each sentence by looking up dozen of other notes or books to fill the gaps. One exercise in his book is made up of two to three smaller ones.